# How should I implement __hash__ and __str__

Tags: python

I have a class called WeakBoundMethod ([source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4574) on codereview.se). I'd like some guidelines about how I should implement `__hash__()`. Also, Python 3 automatically provides a `__repr__()` function, so I guess I shouldn't bother redefining it then (?). What about `__str__()`, which I understand is a human readable text representation of the object; should I define that as well? any guidelines?

About the hashing function...
I'd like it to generate the hash based on the `__self__` and `__func__` of the bound method it is wrapping. How can I do that?

Comment: Unless you plan to make WeakBoundMethods hash keys, there's no need to implement `__hash__`. And if you do, they should be immutable and you must implement `__eq__` too.

Comment: @delnan This is more of a learning project than anything, so there's no harm in implementing them. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If in doubt, don't implement magic methods**. The defaults are there for a reason and will be fine. In your case, it's completely unnecessary to implement `__hash__` (and if you would implement it, you'd have to implement `__eq__` as well) unless you expect someone to have a set or dictionary of methods.

`__str__` can be useful. In your case, its result should include:

- The class name, to avoid confusion with anything else
- Whether the function is alive or not
- If it is alive, its `str()` result to identify the function, say, by name

Comment: This isn't a real project. I'm learning how to use Python, and I'd like to learn how to write hash functions as well. :)

Comment: @Paul Well, this class shouldn't have a `__hash__` function. Usually, the best way to implement it is to hash over some representation of the class, for example `hash((self.a, self.b))`

Answer (score 0):

9 years late to the party, but since this came up at the top of search results for me...

Regarding:

> Also, Python 3 automatically provides a **repr**() function, so I guess I shouldn't bother redefining it then (?). What about **str**(), which I understand is a human readable text representation of the object; should I define that as well? any guidelines?

The default implementations are fine until they aren't (ie. until you want something more useful).

Case in point:

```
class Message:
    _msg: str

    def __init__(self, msg: str):
        self._msg = msg

    # ... other custom behavior that makes this more useful than just a string


print(Message("asdf"))       # '<__main__.Wat object at 0x104a99128>'
print(str(Message("asdf")))  # '<__main__.Wat object at 0x104a991d0>'
print(repr(Message("asdf"))) # '<__main__.Wat object at 0x104a991d0>'
```

Sure, the defaults exist, but if you have something that's helpful to print to screen, logs, etc. is the `<module.class object at address>` format really helpful?

Contrast that with...

```
class Message:
    _msg: str
    _urgent: bool

    def __init__(self, msg: str, urgent:bool = False):
        self._msg = msg
        self._urgent = urgent

    @classmethod
    def urgent(cls, msg: str) -> "Message":
        return cls(msg, urgent=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if not self._urgent:
            return self._msg

        return f"URGENT: {self._msg.upper()}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({self})"

    # ... other custom behavior that makes this more useful than just a string


print(Message("hey there!"))                   # hey there!
print(str(Message("hey there!")))              # hey there!
print(str(Message.urgent("look behind you")))  # URGENT: LOOK BEHIND YOU
print(repr(Message.urgent("look behind you"))) # Message(URGENT: LOOK BEHIND YOU)
```

The advice above, "If in doubt, don't implement magic methods." is partially true (if you don't need functionality, why implement it?) but it also seems to indicate that you probably shouldn't. Magic methods are actually meant to be overwritten - it's how we enrich our classes with useful behavior that is 'built in' to Python and avoid a lot of otherwise necessary boilerplate to serialize to strings, create custom iterators or context managers, etc.